# How do I merge 2 datasets in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I've tried to run this line of code in my Rstudio and it wored perfectly, I inten copying same analysis to my kaggle acct as a porject but the merge function raised an error and has stop my program from working.

Here's an example of the code:

```
products <- merge(products, product_name_translation, by = "product_category_name")
products <- products %>%
  select(!product_category_name) %>%
  relocate(product_category_name_english)
```

Here's the error I received

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x): 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
> Traceback:

there exists column name `product_category_name` in both datasets, and it is worked perfectly on R studio, but not on kaggle notebook

Comment: Can you double check that there's not an extra space or something in the column name? Try `intersect(names(products), names(product_name_translation))` and check that you get `"product_category_name"` exactly returned as one of the shared columns.

Comment: I think the key is in the "**uniquely** valid column name". I can reproduce your error if I create a data frame with two columns named `product_name_translation` and another data frame with one such column. Check that you have not somehow duplicated a column with the same name.